# 3D Stacked Bar Chart GUI using Qt?

Tags: python, c++, gui, charts, qt

I am searching for a library I can use with **C++ Qt** preferably or PyQt, that can draw 3D Stacked Bars Chart as this [picture](https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/doc/en/UserGuide/images/3D_Stacked_Bars/Sample_3D_Stacked_Bars.png?v=73263), I have already found some libraries that can draw stacked charts but in 2D as [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-stackedbarchartdrilldown-example.html), or others to draw 3D bars but **not** stacked as [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/q3dbars.html)

If any have any recommendations it would be helpful.